# Linked checkboxes in Userform and Worksheet

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a table format questionnaire to be filled on Userform. There are some sections that to be answered only by check-boxes.Those check-boxes are exist in both worksheet and userform. When the user click the box in the userform it need to be ticked in worksheet as well(I don't know if it is possible).

Comment: If you would link your Check-box on your sheet to a cell it will say false or true when checkbox is clicked. Just create a macro that runs from your userform to change that cell's value to true or false when the checkbox on your userform is clicked.

Comment: Just writing TRUE or FALSE into the selected cells is not working for me because the questionnaire needs to be print out as a word document which will show what selections has been made by users.

Comment: So why wouldn't it be possible on another (possibly hidden) sheet?

Comment: Sorry I could not  understand what you mean by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some `If` statements to assign the same value to the worksheet checkbox on the click or change event of the UserForm checkbox.

Something like:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).CheckBox1.Value = True
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).CheckBox1.Value = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Even cleaner then mine :)!

Comment: @JvdV I did learn something new with yours though. Always good to have multiple ways to do something!

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am getting run time error 438 but I think it is not related with your solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Link your checkboxes on your sheet to a cell (whichever cell, even on another sheet)

[image]

**2)** Here is the code you could alter to your liking. Make sure to use it as a clickevent on your checkboxes on your userform:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("D3").Value = True
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("D3").Value = False

End Sub
```

**3)** Outcome will be like:

[image]